# Installing a precomplied python package anywhere else than the python path

Tags: python, virtualenv, precompiled

I was trying to install psutil (on which my own script depends) on a computer that does not have Visual Studio 2008, so I get the "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error. I don't have mingw32 either. I tried installing the precompiled version for Python 2.7, but it searches the registry, finds Python installed in C:\Python2.7\ and tries to install it there without allowing me to change the install path.

I used virtualenv to create a virtual environment from my Python 2.7 in a dir c:\MyVitualEnv, and that's where I want to install psutil. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I may be out of date here, but as far as I know, Windows binary package installers don't know about virtualenv, so there is no _direct_ way to do what you want. But you can do it indirectly in three ways: (1) Extract the files from the package and install them manually. (2) Install the package globally, copy the relevant files into your venv, uninstall the package globally. (3) Extract just the pyd/dll files, figure out where to drop them into the source distribution, and update their timestamps, so `python setup.py install` will use the already-built copies instead of trying to build them.

Comment: If any of those sound attractive to you, but you need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: How is this off topic? Doesn't it fall under "software tools commonly used by programmers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to solve this problem with psycopg2 and gdal. Use easy_install from your virtualenv with the executable as the argument. I'll pretend the file psutil-0.7.0.win32-py2.7.exe is in C:\ for the sake of an example. On the command prompt,

```
C:\> C:\MyVitualEnv\Scripts\activate.bat
(MyVitualEnv) C:\> easy_install psutil-0.7.0.win32-py2.7.exe
```

`activate.bat` just sets up the environment to use the virtualenv, so the call to `easy_install` will find `C:\MyVitualEnv\Scripts\easy_install` and a number of other appropriate environment variables will be set.

You can even use pip to uninstall it later:

```
(MyVitualEnv) C:\> pip uninstall psutil
```

Note: You can't use pip to do the install. Only easy_install works.

Seems to work with both setuptools and distribute, although I haven't actually tried to use a library after doing this with distribute.

I think this works because the executable is really just a zip file containing some well known file structure. (Perhaps the internal structure of the executable is the same as an egg file.) There must be some kind of standard way of building these binaries, and that method produces these "easy_install compatible" executables. I can't tell you what the details of that process are, though. If someone could enlighten me, I'd be happy to add it to this answer.

Enjoy!

Comment: It actually works nicely. I like this because I don't have to change anything to my deployment process, just change a line in my installation batch file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two computers (A) and (B), where (A) you used to develop the script and now you'd like it on (B).  If you still have access to (A), you could use use [ps2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) to bundle it into an executable on (A) for use on (B).  You'll have to include the MSVisual C runtime though.